# Tauri and NextJS Get directory on installed app

Tags: rust, next.js, tauri

I am building a desktop app with Tauri and Next, and I have a platform where users are able to download files. Once a file is downloaded, it is usually executed as a .exe file. After the execution, there is a prompt where the user is asked to select an installation path that is OS-controlled, not by me. Any ideas on how I can control it or how I can know the installation path that has been selected by the user?

This is what I have so far in Rust for opening the executable file:

```rust
// Prevents additional console window on Windows in release, DO NOT REMOVE!!
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![execute_executable])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

#[tauri::command]
async fn execute_executable(file_path: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
    let output = Command::new(&file_path)
        .output()
        .map_err(|_| format!("Failed to execute file: {}", file_path))?; // opens the executable file for execution

    if !output.status.success() {
        let stderr = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr);
        return Err(format!("Execution failed: {}", stderr));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```